# SFSafariViewController using Objective-C

Tags: xcode, safari, xcode7, keychain

What is the best way to implement SFSafariViewController using Objective-C. I currently have a UITableView and each of them leads to a different website. May I know how can I code each of them to load a different website in SFSafariViewController using Objective-C, not Swift? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a version that checks the iOS version to handle iOS 8, and open links in safari if SFSafariViewController isn't compatible

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com"]];
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion hasPrefix:@"9"]) {
    SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
    [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
}
```

Then also call this to handle the done button

```
- (void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(nonnull SFSafariViewController *)controller {
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}
```

Comment: Don't do that, it won't even work on iOS 10. Do `if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil) {`

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion hasPrefix:@"9"]

*facepalm* at that

Answer (score 20):

This will work with newer versions like 10.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com"]];
if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil) {
    SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
    [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
}
```